# How to use Tuple.Create() method to create an tuple like this

Tags: c#, tuples

If I write code like this:

```
var a = Tuple.Create(1,2,3);
var b = Tuple.Create(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a);
```

It actually creates a Tuple whose type is:

```
Tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,Tuple<Tuple<int,int,int>>>
```

How could I use Tuple.Create() method to create a tuple like:

```
Tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,Tuple<int,int,int>>
```

Comment: Why would you prefer such a tuple over a data object with named properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386921(v=vs.110).aspx) says, return value of `Tuple.Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>` method is `System.Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>` where 8-th argument is wrapped into the new tuple. If you are passing tuple as last argument, then this tuple will be wrapped into the tuple and you'll get `Tuple<Tuple<>>` as you have it now.

[Implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,dd7c4a37c4fa0fd4) of this creation method is pretty straight-forward:

```
static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(
   T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7, T8 item8)
{
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>(
        item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, new Tuple<T8>(item8));
}
```

as you can see the last argument is simply wrapped and passed to constructor. There is nothing you can do here.

But you have at least two options. You can use tuple constructor directly. Of course, you will have to specify tuple type manually in that case. Or you can create your own creation method without last argument wrapping, which will do type inference for you:

```
static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8> CreateTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(
    T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7, T8 item8)
    where T8: ITuple
{
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(
        item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8);
}
```

Usage

```
var a = Tuple.Create(1,2,3);
var b = CreateTuple(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a);
// Tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,Tuple<int,int,int>>
```

Note that with C# 7 we have Value Tuples which provide much better interface with nicely named properties. E.g.

```
var point = (x: 1, y: 2, z: 3);
var rocket = (id: 1, speed: 100, location: point);

// rocket.location.y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. According to MSDN:
[Tuple Class (System)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The .NET Framework directly supports tuples with one to seven elements. In addition, you can create tuples of eight or more elements by nesting tuple objects in the Rest property of a Tuple object.

Because of that you get `Tuple` with `Tuple` as 8th element.